Cannot use nbsp.materialfilepicker:1.9.1 because it generate org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException error
When compiling the app, I receive the following message:

Caused by:
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
Could not resolve all files for configuration
':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. Followed by: Caused by:
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not
find com.nbsp:materialfilepicker:1.9.1.

Below is my build.gradle file
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
       compileSdk 33
      
       defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.teste.filepicker"
       minSdk 19
       targetSdk 33
       versionCode 4
       versionName "4.9b"
       testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }

 compileOptions {
     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 }
 buildTypes {
      release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
 }

 namespace 'com.teste.filepicker'

 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
      variant.outputs.all { output ->
      def project = "Filepiker"
      def newApkName = project + ".apk"
      outputFileName = new File(newApkName)
      }
 }

}

dependencies {

 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
 implementation 'com.nbsp:materialfilepicker:1.9.1'

}

And the settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
   repositories {
      google() 
      mavenCentral()
      gradlePluginPortal()
   }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
   repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
   repositories {
      google()
      mavenCentral()
      jcenter()
      maven {url 'https://jitpack.io'}
   }
}

rootProject.name = "Filepiker "
include ':app'

The build.gradle file ( Filepiker )
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '8.5.1' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '8.5.1' apply false
}

The problem seems to be that Gradle can no longer find the module com.nbsp:materialfilepicker:1.9.1
How can I fix this?

I solved the problem by finding the aar file of the library that is available at:
https://maven.moxtra.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/github/icerockdev/MaterialFilePicker/1.9.1/
and importing the file locally using the FILE -> PROJECT STRUCTURE option and importing the dependency.
The file is not available in mavenCentral because it is an old library.

The library that you have mentioned have not been maintained in several years and has probably been hosted on JCenter.
Due to the fact JCenter is shutting down, it means the owners of that library need to migrate it to mavenCentral.
Your options are to:

Clone the repository and work on it so it is up to date with the current API levels
Find more recent alternative libraries that help you do what you are after

